# Choosing an MSChart-Extension tool from button click

Tags: c#, mschart

I am using [MSChart-Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/357817/MSChart-Extension-Zoom-and-Pan-Control) and I would like the option to choose the Zoom, Pan and Select tools from a button, as well as from the `ContextMenuStrip`. I feel like the easiest way is to simulate a click from the `ContextMenuStrip.Items` collection

Here is what I've got. In my form I have this

```
private void zoomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chart.ChangeTool("Zoom");
}
```

And in `MSChartExtensions.cs` I have this

```
public static void ChangeTool(this Chart sender, string option)
{
    Chart chart = sender;

    foreach(ToolStripItem item in chart.ContextMenuStrip.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text == option)
        {
            item.PerformClick();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This successfully chooses the tool from the collection. However, I am getting a `System.ArgumentNullException` in the `SetChartControlState` method. I have stepped through the code and I see that when the application enters `ChartContext_ItemClicked`, the sender's source control is null. I've dug through MSDN, and [found this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.sourcecontrol%28vs.80%29.aspx)

> A Control that represents the control that is displaying the shortcut menu. **If no control has displayed the shortcut menu, the property returns a null reference** (Nothing in Visual Basic).

So I assume that because no right-click menu (`ContextMenuStrip`) is shown, the source control is null. Is there a way around this? How can I get this working? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Change the `ChangeTools()` method to this

```
// In MSChartExtensions.cs
public static void ChangeTool(this Chart sender, string option)
{
    if (option == "Zoom")
        SetChartControlState(sender, MSChartExtensionToolState.Zoom);
    else if (option == "Select")
        SetChartControlState(sender, MSChartExtensionToolState.Select);
    else if (option == "Pan")
        SetChartControlState(sender, MSChartExtensionToolState.Pan);
    else if (option == "Zoom Out")
    {
        Chart ptrChart = sender;
        WindowMessagesNativeMethods.SuspendDrawing(ptrChart);
        ptrChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
        ptrChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
        ptrChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
        WindowMessagesNativeMethods.ResumeDrawing(ptrChart);
    }
}
```

And then call this method like how I did in the question

```
// In the form
private void zoomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chart.ChangeTool("Zoom"); // As an example
}
```

If anyone has a better way of doing this, feel free to let me know